# Not getting the difference between two list by using linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have two lists as follows:

```
var SeparatedEmployees = (from s in DataContext.HRM_EMP_TRMN.AsEnumerable()
                                  where s.TRMN_FINL_STUS == "SA" && ((Convert.ToDateTime(s.TRMN_EFCT_DATE)).Year).ToString() == Year && ((Convert.ToDateTime(s.TRMN_EFCT_DATE)).Month).ToString() == HRMD_COMMON.ReturnMonthName(Month)
                                  join e in DataContext.VW_HRM_EMPLOYEE on s.EMP_CODE equals e.EMP_CODE
                                  where e.ACTIVE_STATUS == "A"
                                  select new HRM_EMP_FINL_STMT_MSTModel
                                  {
                                      EMP_CODE = s.EMP_CODE,
                                      EMP_NAME = e.EMP_NAME,
                                      DIVI_CODE = e.DIVI_CODE,
                                      DIVI_NAME = e.DIVI_NAME,
                                      EMP_DESIG_CODE = e.EMP_DESIG_CODE,
                                      EMP_DESIG_NAME = e.EMP_DESIG_NAME,
                                      JOINING_DATE = HRMD_COMMON.ReturnOnlyDate(Convert.ToDateTime(e.JOINING_DATE)),
                                      TRMN_TYPE = HRMD_COMMON.ReturnTerminationType(s.TRMN_TYPE),
                                      TRMN_EFCT_DATE = HRMD_COMMON.ReturnOnlyDate(Convert.ToDateTime(s.TRMN_EFCT_DATE)),
                                      LAST_SAL_PROS_MON = HRMD_COMMON.ReturnMonthName(s.LAST_SAL_PROS_MON),
                                      FINL_STMT_REM = s.TRMN_REM

                                  }).ToList();

        var ConfirmedEmployees = (from c in DataContext.HRM_EMP_FINL_STMT_MST.AsEnumerable()
                                  where ((Convert.ToDateTime(c.FINL_STMT_DATE)).Year).ToString() == Year && ((Convert.ToDateTime(c.FINL_STMT_DATE)).Month).ToString() == HRMD_COMMON.ReturnMonthName(Month)
                                  join e in DataContext.VW_HRM_EMPLOYEE on c.EMP_CODE equals e.EMP_CODE
                                  join s in DataContext.HRM_EMP_TRMN on c.EMP_CODE equals s.EMP_CODE
                                  select new HRM_EMP_FINL_STMT_MSTModel
                                  {
                                      EMP_CODE = s.EMP_CODE,
                                      EMP_NAME = e.EMP_NAME,
                                      DIVI_CODE = e.DIVI_CODE,
                                      DIVI_NAME = e.DIVI_NAME,
                                      EMP_DESIG_CODE = e.EMP_DESIG_CODE,
                                      EMP_DESIG_NAME = e.EMP_DESIG_NAME,
                                      JOINING_DATE = HRMD_COMMON.ReturnOnlyDate(Convert.ToDateTime(e.JOINING_DATE)),
                                      TRMN_TYPE = HRMD_COMMON.ReturnTerminationType(s.TRMN_TYPE),
                                      TRMN_EFCT_DATE = HRMD_COMMON.ReturnOnlyDate(Convert.ToDateTime(s.TRMN_EFCT_DATE)),
                                      LAST_SAL_PROS_MON = HRMD_COMMON.ReturnMonthName(s.LAST_SAL_PROS_MON),
                                      FINL_STMT_REM = s.TRMN_REM
                                  }).ToList();
```

Tyring to remove the items from the first list, which are also in second list.

```
 var FinalSeparatedEmployees = (from item in SeparatedEmployees
                                      where !ConfirmedEmployees.Contains(item)
                                      select item).ToList();
```

Tried this one too:

```
FinalSeparatedEmployees = SeparatedEmployees.Except(ConfirmedEmployees).ToList<HRM_EMP_FINL_STMT_MSTModel>();
```

But not getting the accurate result. What I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use EMP_CODE because your objects are not comparable.

```
var ids = ConfirmedEmployees.Select(x => x.EMP_CODE).ToList();
var FinalSeparatedEmployees = (from item in SeparatedEmployees
                                  where !ids.Contains(item.EMP_CODE)
                                  select item).ToList();
```

Comment: Great, its working, but how its not comparable? I returned the same model in both list, didn't I?

Comment: Yes, but c# doesn't know what properties to compare. If you want to go that path you have to define a class with these properties and implement IEquatable<T>, then create an instance of that class in your selects.